# Auto Renewing Certifications for ADFS

Tags: powershell, automation, ssl-certificate, adfs, auto-renewing

We are using ADFS and the certs expire every 2 months and can be renewed manually but we want to create an automation for auto renewal. Can someone walk me through how to do this through either PowerShell or any other Microsoft platform?

Thanks,

I have searched these PowerShell commands but would need to put them together.

```
Connect-MsolService
Update-MSOLFederatedDomain –DomainName
Set-AdfsSslCertificate
Restart-Service ADFSSRV
```

Trying to understand more

Comment: Welcome to SO, Emmanuel. Please copy and paste, as text, the commands you have put together. If it works, great! If it does not, describe in detail how it does not work and include any error messages, as text, in the question. That is the point at which SO can help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help